# Trying to add new rows in a datatable with fnAddTr() in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to add a new row to an already created datatable, but if before adding the row I call `fnClearTable()` I get a 404 NOT FOUND error, if I do not clear the table before it simply does not work, here is the code:

```
table = $("#elem_info_table").dataTable( {
  "bServerSide": true,
  "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
  "bJQueryUI": true,
  "bAutoWidth": false
 } );
table.fnClearTable();
table.fnAddTr($('<tr onClick="zoomElem(this)" style="background-color:'+color+'"><td>'+colorSquema[element]["element"]+"</td><td>"+colorSquema[element]["measurement"]+'</td><td><img src='+imgSrc+'radiolog/images/icon-ok.png/></td></tr>')[0]);
```

PS: I am using this script for the fnAddTr function https://code.google.com/p/regimun/source/browse/trunk/media/js/dataTables.fnAddTr.js?r=81

Comment: The example here (http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/6092/fnaddtr-plugin-ntr.getelementsbytagname-is-not-a-function/p1) makes me think your table is no more a Datatable after calling the fnClearTable() method no?